# getComputedStyle text-decoration inherit

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, firefox

**getComputedStyle** fails to get `text-decoration` property inherited, but can get `font-size`.

Failed in **Firefox 25** and **GoogleChrome 30**.

> Note: In **Internet Explorer 10** work!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        #parent
        {
            font-size: 38px;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <p id="child">Test</p>
    </div>
    <script>
        var elem = document.getElementById("child");

        document.write("text-decoration:"+window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("text-decoration"));
        document.write("<br>");
        document.write("text-decoration:"+document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("text-decoration"));
        document.write("<hr>");
        document.write("font-size:"+window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("font-size"));
        document.write("<br>");
        document.write("font-size:"+document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("font-size"));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It is a fault of mine, or browsers that failed?

Comment: Note that it's not a good idea to use `document.write` or `document.writeln` for debugging code. Instead, use something like `console.log` - you don't have to deal with HTML issues, and you'll be able to manage logging more easily.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but it does not apply to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text-decoration` isn't supposed to inherit, even though the parent text decoration affects the child text. This is unlike `font-size`, which does inherit.

That being said, this definitely looks like an IE bug. While `window.getComputedStyle()` is reporting in IE10 as inherited, it's interesting to note that the F12 developer tools say otherwise.

References:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/text-decoration